# How to check my Cassandra database connection string in asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net-core, cassandra

How to check my Cassandra DB connection string using asp.net core. This is my code

```
Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint('**').withPort("**").build();
Session session = cluster.connect("**");
```

This is my error
1)'Cluster' does not contain a definition for 'builder'
2)'Cluster' does not contain a definition for 'connect' and no accessible extension method 'connect'
accepting a first argument of type 'Cluster' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
assembly reference?)

Comment: what version of the driver?

Comment: 3.16.3 cassandra driver